# high speed list folding and accumulation in F#

Tags: list, f#

So I have a question about how to fold through two lists to produce a new list (or array, or sequence or whichever basic data type is the fastest), because I was using List.Fold and the `::` operator to build a list when I realized that I was essentially producing a billion immutable lists...This seems like it would be slower than traditional for loops, and I am wondering if what I am doing is the "correct" way to solve my problem in F#...

Here is what I've got so far.  I am trying to build a graph structured as `Dictionary<string,Node>*Edge list` with the inputs being a list of nodes and a list of edges.  Each node has a slot for an adjacency list (and I'm not in love with these lists, I just don't know which data type is the best yet...) of edges (so that I only have to look up a node).  My build_graph is attempting to take the list of nodes and list of edges, and search through all of the edges for each node and build a new list of nodes with the adjacency lists populated inside them...

So here is the code...(tried to space it so the lines weren't ridiculously long)

```
let build_graph (nodes:Node<'a> list) (edges:Edge<'a> list) (g:Graph<'a>) = 
    let nlist = List.fold(fun nlist node 
                           -> let adjlist = 
                                List.fold(fun adj edge 
                                            -> if edge.Node1.Name = node.Name or edge.Node2.Name = node.Name
                                                then edge::adj
                                                else adj) [] edges
                              node.Adjacent = Some(adjlist) |> ignore 
                              node::nlist
                              ) [] nodes
    match g with 
    | Dictionary_Graph(_,_) -> let dict = new Dictionary<string,Node<'a>>()
                               List.iter(fun node -> dict.Add(node.Name,node)) nlist |> ignore
                               Dictionary_Graph(dict,edges)
    | ConcurrentDictionary_Graph(_,_) -> let dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,Node<'a>>()

                                         List.iter(fun node -> dict.AddOrUpdate(node.Name,node,(fun k v -> node)) |> ignore) nlist |> ignore
                                         ConcurrentDictionary_Graph(dict,edges)
```

Is this the correct way to solve the problem?  If it isn't correct, is there a faster way to do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: It looks like `List.map` would work here and is almost certainly faster.  If you don't need any of the list features, array is often faster as well

Comment: *"when I realized that I was essentially producing a billion immutable lists..."* Keep in mind that lists in F# are structurally shared. If you add an item at the front of a list of N elements, it takes O(1) time, not O(N), because it just has to add one item at the front, and the rest of the "new" list **is** the "old" list. So the `::` operator is not as inefficient as you may think it is.

Comment: *"This seems like it would be slower than traditional for loops"* Have you measured? What did you find?

Comment: Not yet...but if adding to the front is O(1), then that isn't what I thought. I'll do some more experimentation when I get a chance..

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with creating new immutable lists repeatedly in F# provided that it's done by prepending - as you are here.  This operation is O(1) so shouldn't be a performance problem.  Indeed Lists are probably the optimal F# collection for this sort of thing.

Moving on to there code, there are some issues.  First of all:

```
node.Adjacent = Some(adjlist) |> ignore
```

This line checks if `node.Adjacent` equals `Some(adjlist)` and then ignores the result of that comparison.  I suspect you intended:

```
node.Adjacent <- Some(adjlist)
```

Using mutability inside a fold is probably a bit of a strange practise which I wouldn't particularly recommend.  I'd suggest you instead opt for creating a new node with the new adjacency list added.

Example:

```
// create new record with adjacency list supplied
{Item = node.Item; Name = node.Name; Adjacent = Some adjlist}
```

Secondly, your second `List.fold` looks like a filter to me.  You could replace:

```
List.fold (fun adj edge -> 
    if edge.Node1.Name = node.Name or edge.Node2.Name = node.Name then edge::adj
    else adj) [] edges
```

with

```
edges 
|> List.filter (fun edge -> edge.Node1.Name = node.Name || edge.Node2.Name = node.Name)
```

This isn't a problem, that part of your code should work but using filter is easier and more concise.

Likewise, your first `List.fold` can be replaced with `List.map`.

The final result might be something like:

```
let buildGraph (nodes:Node<'a> list) (edges:Edge<'a> list) (g:Graph<'a>) = 
    let nlist = 
        nodes |> List.map (fun node ->
             let adjlist = 
                 edges |> List.filter(fun edge -> edge.Node1.Name = node.Name || edge.Node2.Name = node.Name)
             {Item = node.Item; Name = node.Name; Adjacent = Some adjlist})
    match g with 
    | DictionaryGraph(_) -> 
        let dict = new Dictionary<string,Node<'a>>()
        List.iter(fun node -> dict.Add(node.Name,node)) nlist |> ignore
        Dictionary_Graph(dict,edges)
    | ConcurrentDictionaryGraph(_) -> 
        let dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,Node<'a>>()
        List.iter(fun node -> dict.AddOrUpdate(node.Name,node,(fun k v -> node)) |> ignore) nlist |> ignore
        ConcurrentDictionaryGraph(dict,edges)
```